# Icosahedron and inscribed cube

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, platonic-solids

We can inscribe a cube in dodecahedron ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065864/five-cubes-in-dodecahedron)), where $12$ faces of dodecahedron give the $12$ edges of the cube.

[image]

Can we inscribe cube in icosahedron?

Comment: Which features would correspond? The $6$/$8$/$12$ faces/vertices/edges of a cube with the ... ?

Comment: I didn't see any connection with the number of vertices/edges/faces between these two. But I thought there could be other way to inscribe a cube in icosahedron; since I don't know it, I posted it as a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dodecahedron and icosahedron are dual to one another. So there would be a way where each vertex of the icosahedron corresponds to an edge of the cube. So you'd have corners of the cube in the centers of *some* of the faces.

[image: Cube in Icosahedron]

[image: Cube in Dodecahedron in Icosahedron]

Pictures created using a Cinderella [Application](http://rawgit.com/IMAGINARY/cinderella-applets-2011-edition/master/showApplet.html?lang=en&which=C3) created by J. Richter-Gebert.